# Limit Proof Check: $\lim _{x \to a} x^4 = a^4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Reviewing limits and I'm afraid I may be making mistakes, just looking for a quick proof check.

$f(x)=x^4$, prove that $\lim _{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=a^4$ by showing how to find $\delta$ .

This is my work. $|x^4 - a^4 | < \epsilon$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta$

Factoring: $|x^2 +a^2||x-a||x+a|< \epsilon$ next we set $|x-a|<1$ which means $-1+a<|x|<1+a$ so that

\begin{align}
 |x^2 +a^2||x-a||x+a|& =((-1+a)^2 +a^2 )((1+a)+a)(x-a))\\
 & = |2a(1+2a^2 -2a)||x-a|\\ 
 & <\epsilon \\
\end{align}

We then have $$\delta =\min\lbrace 1, \frac{\epsilon}{ |2a(1+2a^2 -2a)|} \rbrace$$

How's it look?

Comment: Wouldnt it be $\delta =min\lbrace 1, \frac{\epsilon}{ |2a(1+2a^2 -2a)|} \rbrace$?

Comment: Er, yeah, I forgot about that part. Let me just fix that.

Comment: Doesn't look good. Inequalities have become equalities, it is not clear that you have obtained an upper bound on $(x^2+a^2)(|x+a|)$.

Answer (score 4):

Alternate Solution.

Need to find a bound for $|x^2 + a^2||x + a|$. Take for instance, $|x - a| < 1$ then

$$|x^2 + a^2||x + a| = |x^2 - a^2 + 2a^2 ||x - a + 2a| = (|x^2 - a^2 + 2a^2 |)(|x - a + 2a|)$$

This does not change the expression since $a^2 - a^2 = 0$ and $a - a = 0$

Using the triangle inequality $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$

$$(|x^2 - a^2 + 2a^2 |)(|x - a + 2a|)$$

$$\le (|x^2 - a^2| + |2a^2 |)(|x - a| + |2a|)$$

$$\le (|x - a||x + a| + |2a^2 |)(|x - a| + |2a|)$$

$$\le (|x - a||x -a + 2a| + |2a^2 |)(|x - a| + |2a|)$$

$$\le (|x - a| \cdot (|x -a| + |2a|) + |2a^2 |)(|x - a| + |2a|)$$

$$|x - a| < 1$$

$$< (1 \cdot (1 + 2|a|) + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)$$

$$< (1 + 2|a| + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)$$

Therefore

$$|x^2 + a^2||x + a| < (1 + 2|a| + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)$$

Therefore

$$|x^2 + a^2||x + a||x - a| < (1 + 2|a| + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)|x - a| < \epsilon$$

$$|x - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{(1 + 2|a| + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)}$$

Take $$\delta = min \lbrace 1, \frac{\epsilon}{(1 + 2|a| + 2|a^2|)(1 + 2|a|)} \rbrace$$

Answer (score 0):

A different factorization
works for all powers
$x^n$.

This is
$x^n-a^n
=(x-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}
$.

If
$|x-a| < 1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
|x^n-a^n|
&=|x-a||\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}|\\
&<|x-a||\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a+1)^ka^{n-1-k}|\\
&\le|x-a|n(|a|+1)^{n-1})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
to make
$|x^n-a^n| < \delta$,
it is enough if
$|x-a|n(|a|+1)^{n-1}
 < \delta$
or
$|x-a|
< \dfrac{\delta}{n(|a|+1)^{n-1}}
$.

Inserting the restriction
$|x-a| < 1$,
this becomes
$|x-a|
< \min(1,\dfrac{\delta}{n(|a|+1)^{n-1}})
$.